# Timing out pure functions

Tags: haskell, timeout, purely-functional

How can I "kill" a pure calculation which is taking too long? I tried

```
import System.Timeout

fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * (fact $ n - 1)

main = do maybeNum <- timeout (10 ^ 7) $ (return . fact) 99999999
          print maybeNum
```

However, this doesn't work. Replace the `(return . fact) 99999999` with a "real" IO function like `getLine` and this works as expected.

Comment: Interesting that if `fact` become "real" IO action (`fact 0 = return 1; fact n = (n *) \`fmap\` (fact $ n - 1)`) then `timeout` works as expected too.

Comment: @MatveyAksenov: I think that's not so much because the function is a real IO action, but because its recursion is, by means of `fmap`, moved into the `IO` monad.

Comment: If you need to timeout arbitrary and potentially malicious code, make sure to test against really simple non-allocating loops, e.g. `let x = x in x` and `let x () = x () in x ()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The point is that

```
return (fact 999999999)
```

immediately returns and doesn't trigger the timeout. It returns a thunk that will be evaluated later.

If you force evaluation of the return value,

```
main = do maybeNum <- timeout (10 ^ 7) $ return $! fact 99999999
          print maybeNum
```

it should trigger the timeout (if you provide a stack large enough so that the timeout happens before the stack overflow).