# Bound the runtime of a computation in haskell

Tags: haskell, artificial-intelligence, sleep, thread-sleep

I'm writing a game AI in Haskell, and I want to search the game state tree for a specified amount of time (i.e. I always want to AI to take 3 seconds to make its decision on what move to make)

How can I do this in a pure language like Haskell? I expect that I'll need to do some diving into threads and such but I would prefer to minimize that as much as I can.

Comment: Use [timeout](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=timeout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea: Combine `timeout` (suggested by @MathematicalOrchid) with mutable variables from [SafeSemaphore](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SafeSemaphore/0.9.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MSampleVar.html) to store intermediate values every time your process computes a partial result:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent.MSampleVar
import System.Timeout

fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n - 1)

tmo :: Int -> ((a -> IO ()) -> IO ()) -> IO (Maybe a)
tmo ms f = do
    mvar <- newSV Nothing
    timeout ms (f (writeSV mvar . (Just $!)))
    readSV mvar

longComp :: (Integer -> IO ()) -> IO ()
longComp save = let loop n = save (fac n) >> loop (n + 1)
                in loop 0

main :: IO ()
main = tmo 10000 longComp >>= print
```

The function passed to `tmo` gets as its first argument an `IO` action that it can use to save intermediate results. If it gets timeouted, the last saved result is returned. The result is converted to WHNF so that the real computation happens in the thread that saves the result, not in the one that processes it when it's returned from `tmo`.

In this variant, the function passed to `tmo` has to save its output, it cannot return it. But it would be easy to modify it so that it's signature would be `(a -> IO ()) -> IO a`.

If you want to keep things more pure I'd suggest to create your own monad that encapsulates this idea without letting `IO` out.

---

**Update:** Note that:

> There is no guarantee that the exception will be delivered promptly, although
>   the runtime will endeavour to ensure that arbitrary delays don't occur. In
>   GHC, an exception can only be raised when a thread reaches a safe point,
>   where a safe point is where memory allocation occurs. Some loops do not
>   perform any memory allocation inside the loop and therefore cannot be
>   interrupted by a throwTo.

(from the documentation of [throwTo](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3athrowTo)). In the example above, `fac` doesn't allocate any memory and so for large numbers it won't get interrupted immediately.

**Update:** I created a small library based on those ideas that defines a monads for computations that can return partial results before returning the final one or dying on a timeout. See https://github.com/ppetr/timeout-with-results

Answer (score 3):

Since the result you're looking for depends on time, this is inevitably going to involve impure code.

It looks like `System.Timeout` from the `base` package provides the ability to run an I/O computation until some timeout (per the comment by leftaroundabout.) So all you need to do is write an `IO` computation that returns the result you're interested in. However... the tricky part is making the `IO` action actually *compute* the result, not just return an unevaluated result. For that, I *think* you need `evaluate` from `Control.Exception`.

Comment: +1 for the insight that a function dependent in time is necessarily impure.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Timeout` is the way to go. It's got a very clean interface, that doesn't feel at all like you're messing with threads.

Searching the game space sounds like a pure computation, and `System.Timeout` runs `IO` actions, so you'll need to wrap the value in `return`, and evaluate the code strictly enough that `timeout` doesn't immediately believe an answer has been returned as soon as it's been evaluated to WHNF.

There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071560/timing-out-pure-functions) of what the code might look like, from a similar problem that I was having.